# Why does Arashigaoka Academy share a name with Wuthering Heights?

Tags: yuri-kuma-arashi

I am currently reading *Aoi Hana*, in which students at a girls' school put up a production of *Wuthering Heights*. Out of curiosity, I went to Google to determine whether the Takarazuka Revue ever produced an adaptation of the same. There apparently was; I noticed on a Wiki page that the Japanese title of the production (and thus, the novel) was *Arashi ga Oka* (嵐が丘).

This brought me to my question: Kureha attends Arashigaoka Academy (嵐が丘学園) in *Yuri Kuma Arashi*, so the name of her school must then be a reference to *Wuthering Heights*. Is there any particular reason why this literary reference fits?

- Are there any specific parallels with YKA (whether the manga, the anime, or the light novels) that would make this reference appropriate?
- Alternatively, is there something about the tone of *Wuthering Heights* that fits one part or another of the YKA franchise?

Comment: There's a [Tumblr post](http://goddamnit-ikuhara.tumblr.com/post/107133465828/juniperstreet-in-less-than-12-hours-yuri-kuma) that mentions: "*Wuthering Heights is a convoluted novel about multi-generational abuse, manipulation, isolation, and obsession.*". There's also [Japanese fans' perception](http://anicobin.ldblog.jp/lite/archives/44050022/comments/9219708/?p=7) that "Yurika, Reia, and Kureha's models are from *Wuthering Heights*' Heathcliff, Catherine, and Cathy". Also, someone's theory on [MAL forum](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1337727&show=340#msg37470117).

Comment: @AkiTanaka I wonder if the same reading holds for the manga: if I remember correctly, the dynamics between characters are a bit different there (e.g. Yurika's relationship to the rest of the characters, Ginko's role, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. All of the links above refer to the anime's, but maybe it's because the manga is less popular, and doesn't seem to be canon (I might answer [your question about anime/manga disctintion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/how-do-the-various-yurikuma-arashi-adaptations-relate-to-each-other) some time)